# UIBarButtonItem call UIActionsheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uiactionsheet

in main view a have an navigationController on click on a row a call the detailview and add a button

seminareListinView.m

```
#import "SeminareListingView.h"
#import "Seminar.h"


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //gehe zurück zum ersten View
    //NSLog(@"Received Data in seminareArray");

    Seminar *dvController = [[Seminar alloc] initWithNibName:@"Seminar" bundle:nil];

    NSString *selectedSeminarURL = [seminarURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSString *selectedNextXMLFile = [kategorienNextXMLFileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    dvController.seminarURLFromXML = selectedSeminarURL;
    //dvController.XMLFile = selectedNextXMLFile;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];


    //Zeige den PDF Download Button
    UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"PDF Download" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];

    //anotherButton.action = @selector(showMenu);

    dvController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;

    [anotherButton release];

    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;


    //[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

in the seminar view a have this method

seminar.m

```
- (void) showMenu
{
    UIActionSheet *myMenu = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                             initWithTitle: @"Überschrift"
                             delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen"
                             destructiveButtonTitle:@"Etwas unwiderrufliches"
                             otherButtonTitles:@"Eins", @"Zwei", nil];
    [myMenu showInView:self.view];
}
```

but i get an error by clicking on Button

```
2011-07-07 12:57:31.009 Seminar App2[4352:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SeminareListingView showMenu]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6305f90'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Comment: [myMenu showInView:self.view]; what it means ur custom method or any ?

Comment: This do not relate to the question, but you should autorelease/release the UIActionSheet in showMenu, otherwise you have a memoryleak.

Comment: did u add UIActionSheetDelegate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"PDF Download" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];
```

Cange to:

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"PDF Download" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:dvController action:@selector(showMenu)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're implementing the `showMenu` method in the `Seminar` class, but you're telling the bar button to call it on the `SeminareListingView` object. If that's the case, then you need to set the bar button's delegate to an instance of the `Seminar` class.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong. Put your barButton ite code into viewDidLoad of Seminar. You are adding target self which denotes to current view of stack while you actually want to assign target to Seminar Controller. So please cut the code(Adding BarButtonItem) from cellForRowMethod to viewDidLoad of Seminar Controller.